# inline divs not working

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get two divs to align next to each other with no gap however I cannot seem to get it to work. I have put my code into a js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rr4uf/

the server status and the knowledgebase seem to work okay however the ticket doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="single docs">

            <div class="section status">

                <h2>Server Status</h2>

                <p>SERVER STATUS WILL GO HERE</p>               
            </div>

            <div class="section kb">

                <h2>Knowledgebase</h2>
                <p>Is your server not listed above?</p>
                <p>Our Knowledgebase contains a wide array of tutorials and general information to help you with the most common issues.</p>

                <a class="button" href="http://www.noouhost.co.uk/clients/knowledgebase.php" title="View Knowledgebase">View Knowledgebase</a>

            </div>

            <div class="section ticket">

                <h2>Support Ticket</h2>
                <p>Cannot find a solution to your problem in our Knowledgebase?</p>
                <p>Submit a ticket to our support team and we will help resolve any issues you're having.</p>

                <a class="button" href="https://www.noouhost.co.uk/clients/submitticket.php" title="Submit Ticket">Submit Ticket</a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set a width of 50% and an additional padding and border - these add up to a total width which is greater than 50%. By applying "box-sizing: border-box;" the padding and border will be included in the 50%. For example:

```
.section.kb {
    width:50%;
    border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-top:0px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

    display:inline-block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Note that you have to add -moz-box-sizing as well because Firefox has not yet implemented this feature wihtout prefix. Otherwise it is pretty well supported even by older IEs.

I have also changed "display: inline" to "display: inline-block".

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/c4wBW/

Comment: thanks guys I manage to get it to work. i just changed the width of the status box to 97,5% and it all lines up! :)

Comment: Please read my post, just changing the width to something obscure like 97,5% will give you unpredictable results later on. For instance you might change the padding of one of the div's. This will cause the alignment of the div's to collapse again, forcing you to try out some new width (for instance 97,3%). You should remove the display:inline and work with the float:left.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but i didnt get your question properly,
do you want to align "section.kb" and "section.ticket" side by side this use this style 
try this:

```
.section.kb {
        width:50%;
        border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
        border-top:0px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        display:table-cell;
    }

    .section.ticket {
        width:50%;
        border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
        border-top:0px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        display:table-cell;
    }
```

i just made both div as table-cell

Comment: that works, the only thing is the right hand box the ticket one does not fit the full width?

Comment: that happens because browser added  "margin:8px" to body make it zero

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- 1: display:inline
- 2: width of each div

**Display inline**

Using display:inline as a means of stacking 2 div's next to each other gives unpredictable results. You are actually telling the browser that the div's have to behave like words and not like letters. Consider this:

```
AA

A A
```

You think that you are getting AA but in reality you are getting an extra space between your div's if you are using display:inline. The solution here is to remove display:inline and use float:left;  instead.

**Width of each div**

In order, for the browser, to calculate the width it's using this formula:

```
width + padding + border = real width
```

What you actually want is this formula:

```
width  = real width
```

To get this you have to change the border-sizing of the div using this code:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
```

Here is an article explaining this: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

And here you will find your update code: http://jsfiddle.net/rr4uf/4/

Answer (score 0):

Please check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rr4uf/1/)

You have to use float in both `div` and adjust width of them.

Comment: i see what you did and that sort of worked but there is a gap between the two boxes, can we add border-left:0px; to the right box and close the gap?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put display:inline-block; to the section.kb and play with the **width** and **float**